# Syntax highlighting for haskell

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047844/handling-404-via-maybe-in-http-conduit) question and just wonder why the comments are weirdly highlighted when the code block uses `<!-- language: lang-haskell -->`. When not specifying any language the comments are properly grayed out. Is this a bug?

Example:

```haskell
-- This is a comment and it is weirdly highlighted
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. The problem here is that you use `<!-- language: lang-haskell -->` instead of the recommended `<!-- language: lang-hs -->` as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

I do not know what exactly `lang-haskell` does to your code but it does not highlight Haskell code correctly, as the `do` keyword in this example is not highlighted correctly and the strings are also not highlighted (when using `lang-haskell`):

```haskell
-- This comment is just for comments sake
main = do
   name <- getLine
   print ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")
```

Using `lang-hs` everything works fine:

```hs
-- This comment is just for comments sake
main = do
   name <- getLine
   print ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")
```

Comment: Since `lang-haskell` does not exist, it will revert to `default` and let the highlighter try to interpret the language. If the post is on a question tagged with [tag:haskell], it will take the `lang-hs` from the tag's settings if none is specified manually.